# F# forwarding of optional parameter

Tags: f#

Is it possible to forward optional parameters e.g:

```
type Type() =
    member this.A(?param) = printfn "%d" <| defaultArg param 0
    member this.B(?param) = this.A(param)  // how to do this ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
    member this.B(?param) = this.A(?param = param)
```

Using `?` when providing a named optional parameter allows you to pass an option.